# Flaky Intel Bluetooth on Ubuntu

Tags: bluetooth, thinkpad

I have a ThinkPad X1 Yoga 1st edition. It has built-in Bluetooth, internally connected to the USB bus (8087:0a2b).

I tried to use it multiple times on Linux (e.g. to use my Bluetooth mouse), but noticed it would only work for 30 to 60 seconds, after which it would become unresponsive until I `systemctl restart bluetooth`.

I first thought it was a Bluez bug; then I tried a USB Bluetooth dongle and it works fine, so there must be a problem with that device.

I recorded some logs while doing the following operations: `rfkill block (device)`, `rfkill unblock (device)`, connect to a Bluetooth mouse.

The last lines in the logs appeared exactly when the mouse stopped responding (blueman reported average transmit and receive power but 0% link quality).

- Kernel: https://hastebin.com/noyoyofemu.coffeescript
- `udevadm monitor -e`: https://hastebin.com/axesudotab.makefile
- some lines from `journalctl -b`: https://hastebin.com/neculogolo.sql

`hci1` is the bad device, `hci0` is the working USB dongle.

I'd like to know if there is a way to debug these issues or a known workaround.

Comment: Do you use wifi?  A lot of the errors are from the wireless device

Comment: @Jeremy31 yes I also use Wi-Fi